# If $I - A$ is invertible, is $\rho(A) < 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, spectral-radius

I know that if $\rho(A) < 1$ then $I-A$ is invertible but I am stuck with the opposite direction. So far I have only shown the trivial $\rho(A) \neq 1$. Any hints?

Comment: One hint is that for this to hold in general, it must hold for $1 \times 1$ matrices

Comment: @Ben That's a nice trick. Thank you.

Comment: $I-A$ is invertible if and only if $1$ isn't an eigenvalue of $A$ (by the very definition of what an eigenvalue is), therefore any condition purportedly equivalent to existence of $(I-A)^{-1}$ (or necessary for this to be the case) must deal with this fact.

Comment: @Gae. Thank you for your comment. That's what I did and mistakenly reach the conclusion about the spectral radius being not equal to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So far I have only shown the trivial $\rho(A) \neq 1$.

Well, $I-(-I)$ is invertible and $\rho(-I)=1$...

Comment: So it doesn't hold in general?

Comment: @cgss Of course it doesn't. E.g. $I-(-kI)$ is invertible for every $k\ge1$ but $\rho(-kI)=|k|\ge1$.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thank you. I will accept your answer once the 5 minutes pass.